# Make mouse cursor custom image change onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouse

First, I am building a website on cargo. There's html editor but I don't think it works that well along with the site builder itself.

I want my custom image mouse cursor image change while it's on click. I've got three problems here:

1. I can't set my default cursor to image. (It was successful in cargo but I don't know how to do this on html editor.)
2. I am not sure how to change my cursor to other image.
3. I want this to make it happen on my whole site not just on single text or image.

Comment: please mark correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!
It's quite simple to do:

Just write the `cursor` property to whatever Selector you want, for the whole WebSite `html {...}` of course.

```css
html {
  background-color: lightgray;
  cursor: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9632/happy.png"), auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

</html>
```

**There are also a lot of default cursors:**
You can check them out here: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/uCwfB

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use a combination of CSS and JavaScript.

CSS class declaring the appropriate cursor definition with a keyword fallback.  Then add a simple onmousedown event to fire the addition of a second CSS class that declares an overriding cursor definition.  Add a second onmouseout event to remove the second class that was added on click.

```
/* keyword fallback example: use pointer, if hand.png doesn't exist */
.cursor-hand {
  cursor: url(hand.png), pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I partially understood about this JS part that you explained but but can you explain what keyword fallback is?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my original answer to include the keyword fallback for the CSS definition of cursor.